# Nominatim does not provide zipcode for some latitude/longitude values

Tags: python, pandas, nominatim, geopy

I am using Nominatim from the GeoPy Python library to obtain Zip Code given Latitude and Longitude.

```
def get_zip_code(x):
    geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent="check_1")

    location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(x['LATITUDE'],x['LONGITUDE']))
    return location.raw['address']['postcode']

df1['ZIPCODE'] = df1.head().apply(lambda x: get_zip_code(x), axis = 1)
```

The code only works for some Lat/Long values and this is the error when it's not working:

```
> in get_zip_code(x)
      geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent="check_1")
      location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(x['LATITUDE'],x['LONGITUDE']))
----> return location.raw['address']['postcode']
> 
> KeyError: 'postcode'
```

My guess is that Nominatim does not have access to all Lat/Long locations and I am wondering if there is something else that can be done to figure this out.
I have also tried to change the number of decimals for each Lat/Long value but it has not worked.

Example of coordinated that work and don't:

Not working: 41.42528, -88.41861
Working: 30.38333, -103.68333

Comment: By https://nominatim.org/2022/06/26/state-of-postcodes.html it is quite possible that there is no postcode at certain coordinates.

Comment: I read it and I am not sure if it does not exist at all or it cannot be obtained using Nominatim?

Comment: Computed Postcode {Nominatim) https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/lonvia/diary/43143